# Why did Obi-Wan use his lightsaber in the Mos Eisley Cantina?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the Mos Eisley Cantina, Obi-Wan uses his light saber to protect Luke from a patron attacking him. Jedi (and I would assume, lightsabers) are very uncommon, so I would imagine Kenobi's attack would attract some attention. Why did Obi-Wan use his lightsaber if he is trying to stay hidden?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**At that point in the story, Kenobi was no longer that concerned with staying hidden.**

---

Prior to the cantina fight in Episode IV, Kenobi was maintaining a low profile. During his time on Tatooine, Ben Kenobi had several run-ins with the local riff-raff. In all such instances, Kenobi avoided using his lightsaber as much as possible for the very reason you bring up. Instead, he would use a combination of Force abilities - mainly telekinesis and mind tricks - to drive away the attackers. This is, in fact, how Kenobi got his reputation of being a "crazy old wizard".

> **LUKE:** You know, I think that R2 unit we bought might have been stolen.
>
> **OWEN:** What makes you think that?
>
> **LUKE:** Well, I stumbled across a recording while I was cleaning him.
> He says he belongs to someone called Obi-Wan Kenobi.
>
> Uncle Owen is greatly alarmed at the mention of his name, glances at
> Beru.
>
> **LUKE:** I thought he might be related to Old Ben. Do you know what he's
> talking about?
>
> Uncle Owen grows angry.
>
> **OWEN:** ***That wizard's just a crazy old man***. Tomorrow I want you to take
> that R2 unit into Anchorhead and have its memory flushed. That'll be
> the end of it. It belongs to us now.

During the scene you mention, Kenobi knew that he and Luke would be leaving the planet soon, so secrecy was not a top priority. He also knew that brandishing the weapon would put a quick end to any other trouble. However, he did indeed realize that the lightsaber might draw the wrong kind of attention, which is largely why he was in a hurry to leave following the confrontation.

**UPDATE:** @Schwern brought up a good point... why would Kenobi knowingly come out of hiding if he's wanted by the Empire? Here's what I think (obviously this is speculation):

Obi-Wan Kenobi was only maintaining a low profile so that he could watch over Luke on Tatooine. If not for that, it's highly possible that both he and Yoda would be helping, if not leading, the Rebellion. As it is, we don't know that The Emperor & Vader are even looking for the pair. In fact, they probably assume that both Jedi Masters are dead by now. Given this fact, now that he is leaving the planet with Luke and heading off to assist and/or join the Rebel forces - who are very much on the Empire's radar - he probably sees little reason in maintaining such a low profile. He may not be broadcasting his location to the galaxy, but he also isn't going through as much trouble to stay hidden. And let's face it - when you're the man who maimed Darth Vader and you're about to get involved with the Rebellion, you're probably not that concerned about a bar fight on a sparsely-populated Outer Rim planet.

Comment: Wouldn't the lightsaber also have the immediate (yet short-term) effect of discouraging any additional confrontations in the team between the initial fight and when they depart?

Comment: @Ellesedil you're right, updated to include that.

Comment: Actually in EU, you are 100% wrong. He used LightSaber before. See "Kenobi" novel. He just lucked out/skilled out to not have anyone notice it.

Comment: @DVK well, I didn't say he never used it, just that he avoided it. I updated to make that clearer, though.

Comment: For the record, we don't know that his reputation is generally that he's a wizard. We only know that it's Owen's opinion (given that he's fully aware that Obi-Wan is a Jedi)

Comment: @Richard Do we even know that's Owen's opinion? I always understood this scene as "he knows pretty well who Ben is, but just says this to silence Luke."

Comment: Owen's stated position, I mean. If you want to ask whether this was his *true* opinion, that would probably be better asked as a new question.

Comment: I don't buy it. His troubles don't stop once he leaves Tatooine, he's Public Enemy #1 with the Empire. He even tells Han, "let's just say we'd like to avoid any Imperial entanglements". Flashing around a lightsaber is guaranteed to give him Imperial entanglements. The Empire probably thought he was dead, now they know he's alive and was last seen talking to a sketchy freighter pilot. Every Bounty Hunter in the Empire would be looking for him.

Comment: @Schwern agreed, but it's only the Empire he's running from - the rest of the galaxy could care less about him. And keep in mind that he was only laying low for Luke's safety, not his own. Now that they're heading off to join the Rebellion - which is probably AS high or higher on The Empire's collective radar, there's not much of a reason to stay hidden anymore.

Comment: "He may not be broadcasting his location to the galaxy" - actually, I'd argue he did in that very scene. How long would the data mining facilities of a totalitarian state like the Empire take to bring up mentions in Tattoine's local tabloid press about a weird guy using an exotic advanced weapon in a bar? Especially a particular kind of weapon that is known to the Empire as a tell-tale sign of someone important being around, one among a handful of people in the galaxy (?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you're probably right about that. He probably just figures that by the time word reaches anyone important, he'll be long gone from Tattooine. At that point, he'll be in the wind so to speak.

Comment: Agreed with Omegacron.  No one in the Empire knew Obi-wan was still alive (he was not "Public Enemy #1"), and he left the planet fairly quickly after this scene.  He had little risk from an incompetent group of droid-recovering grunts -- whereas avoiding being blown out of the sky by a Star Destroyer or something is an entirely different level of concern.  Further, most lightsabers were in the hands of non-Jedi thanks to the majority of Jedi being exterminated....

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Mos Eisley is like New York. People don't give a second glance. It took all of three seconds for the music to start and everyone to go back to their drink. "Old man kills mean alien in bar fight with energy sword"...not that exciting of a headline. They just did't care.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I'm not sure what New York is like, as I have never been there and it is too far away from my place to have any kind of a reputation for anything particular, but in a "properly organized" totalitarian surveillance state, I'd totally expect no-one to give a second glance: No-one would want to show a sign that could look like they have anything to do with what just happened. Towards, for example, a Stormtrooper patrol that might enter the place not too soon ahead.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - within the US, New Yorkers have a reputation for being jaded, selfish, and rude. Like most stereotypes, it's not true. Well, let's say it's only partly true.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - also, and I know I'm about 9 months late on this, but I should point out that The Empire is not what we would consider a totalitarian surveillance state - at least, not in the Outer Rim territories. On an inner planet, sure, but The Empire barely had a presence on Tattooine, let alone any kind of organized surveillance network. Even the population of Tattooine itself wasn't organized in any real fashion - it was just loose communities of people clustered around the more survivable areas of the desert.

Answer (score 28):

In short, he goes for his lightsaber because his and Luke's lives are in *imminent* danger. Both smugglers have proven resistant to Jedi mind tricks, Luke is lying on the floor with a possible head wound and the smuggler is waving a blaster around in a crowded bar room. Disarming the smuggler (literally and figuratively) is the quickest and safest way to prevent any further injuries.

> *The creature’s chrome pistol fired once, blowing a hole in the door. Then the torso peeled away as neatly as had the body of the rodent, its two cauterized sections falling in opposite directions to lie motionless on the cool stone.
> Only then did the suggestion of a sigh escape from Kenobi; only then did his body appear to relax. Bringing the lightsaber down, he flipped it carefully upward in a reflex saluting motion which ended with the deactivated weapon resting innocuously on his hip.*
>
> *That final movement broke the total quiet which had enshrouded the room. Conversation resumed, as did the movement of bodies in chairs, the scraping of mugs and pitchers and other drinking devices on tabletops. The bartender and several assistants appeared to drag the unsightly corpses out of the room, while the mutilated human vanished wordlessly into the crowd, cradling the stump of his gun arm and counting himself fortunate.*
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope : Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28novel%29)</sup></sub>

Additionally, we know from the *new* Junior novelisation ([*Star Wars: A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)) that lightsabers aren't unheard-of in the Empire, just very rare and considered to be drastically antiquated. Possessing one doesn't seem to mark you out as a Jedi, just someone with a bit of a Jedi fetish:

> *“Yeah, hard to miss the sword, pal. **Of course I know what a lightsaber
> is. I wonder what antique trash heap he found it in.”***
>
> *The lightsaber was the chosen weapon of the Jedi Order, who served as
> peacekeepers in the Old Republic—pre-Emperor Palpatine’s takeover.
> There was some religious mumbo jumbo about meditation and something
> called the Force. A great big wad of nonsense, if you asked Han. Their
> kind had been extinct so long they were practically ancient history.*

That being said, the (canon) *[Star Wars Original Trilogy Stories Collection](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Original_Trilogy_Stories)* has a slightly different take on it. The possession of a lightsaber evidently does mark you out as a Jedi.

> “You just watch yourself,” Evazan said. “We’re wanted men!” Obi-
> Wan drew his lightsaber to defend Luke. Everyone in the cantina
> knew that someone with a lightsaber was sure to be a Jedi Knight and,
> therefore, not someone that they wanted to fight. After that, no one
> else bothered Obi-Wan and Luke. Once again, the Force had saved
> them.

Comment: In the movie he just says he doesn't like Luke and neither does his friend.  Luke says "I'll be careful", then the Alien snarks "You'll be dead" and maybe shoves him, but doesn't brandish a weapon or do anything life threatening.  Ben even asks if he could buy the Alien a drink.

Comment: @JoeC - You are mistaken; http://i.stack.imgur.com/25WIF.png

Comment: Its not even as subtle as Richard's screenshot, the shot with the severed arm clearly shows a blaster.

Comment: @JoeC - the bartender can also be heard shouting "no blasters, no blasters" in the movie - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIzAaY2Jm-s#t=400

Comment: Wow, 20 odd years later, and they are already ancient history. Feels like talking about IT tech.

Answer (score 8):

Unlike the previous answer that states this is a plot-flaw, I think this was written on purpose to introduce the lightsabers as soon as possible in the series. After all, lightsabers are one of the coolest things about star wars.

Actually, it's not only about introducing us the lightsabers, but to introduce them to Luke, since he is going to become a Jedi.

And as most previous answers have stated, Obi-Wan doesn't need to maintain a low profile any more, there is a new hope and the return of the Jedi is not far away.

Comment: So do you think Obi Wan intentionally used the lightsaber when he didn't need to just to introduce Luke to Jedi stuff?

Comment: On the contrary, maybe he needed to use it or was more efficient as other answers have stated, but I think he also wanted to introduce Luke (and more importantly "us") to Jedi stuff

Comment: @SJuan76 Actually, I've just watched again, and he wasn't knocked off, he was pushed backwards and he saw the whole scene and how an arm (holding a laser gun) was cut off and then a closeup of Luke looking amazed about what just happened. But then again, we are all Luke (aren't we?)

Answer (score 5):

Nobody's given one possible out of universe explanation - Lucas originally intended lightsabers to be mundane, common weapons. There is even [pre-production art](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-stormtrooper-lightsabers-concept-art/) showing Stormtroopers wielding them. So Ben is just using the one weapon he possesses.

[image: stormtrooper with lightsaber]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  While the information about the pre-production art is an interesting point, typically answers are intended to be in-universe unless the question specifically requests otherwise.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could find some of the preproduction images of Stormtroopers wielding them and [edit] it in to back up your assertion that they were originally meant to be common.

Comment: @DavidW Of course out of universe answers are perfectly acceptable though.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Obi-Wan doesn't choose to use the saber, but he's left no other choice.** He first tries to use diplomacy/bribe/suggestion, saying "This little one's not worth the effort. Come, let me get you something." Luke then gets thrown across the room into a table, and the *two* thugs draw blasters. The bartender cries out a warning about the blasters and dives for cover. Obi-Wan watches them for a half-second as they start to attack, then slices them up. **What else would/could Obi-Wan have used at that point, that would have been preferable?**
2. The jumbled riff-raff and scum in the cantina may likely not not know about Jedi, or their weapons, or even if they do, may not think that the Empire would be interested, or that they would reward being given information. **The Jedi are supposed to be extinct, so someone with a lightsaber is probably just another dangerous weirdo.**
3. **That cantina was clearly a place where patrons fighting and even killing each other wasn't that uncommon or particularly disturbing to the patrons or owner**, especially if you paid a cleaning fee. That's why Obi-Wan (who knows the place) goes there arrange a no-TSA flight to Alderaan. **So it's not unreasonable to expect that lightsaber use could go unreported, at least for long enough to escape the planet.**
4. As seen in the "not the droids you're looking for" scene, **the Imperials are questioning everyone about droids, not Jedi or lightsabers. The Imperials themselves have no idea there is a Jedi around, yet.**
5. **Many of the other patrons likely have their own secrets and are probably not anxious for Imperial attention**, either. So even if someone did make the connection that that was an old Jedi weapon, so the Imperials might reward information about it, most people that informed who would be in that cantina would tend to be unlikely to go to the Imperials with it, unless they're a professional informant or bounty hunter.
6. **Obi-Wan knows how to handle the aftermath, too.** As Obi-Wan says, "the Force can have a strong influence on the weak-minded" - he may be able to use the Force to suggest that people not dwell on the type of weapon he used, and suggest that they go with their instinct to not mess with the guy who just cut two dangerous thugs down. He is also perceptive and resourceful and can likely size up whether anyone is thinking of running to the Imperials crying lightsaber.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm going to get down-voted for this, but I honestly thought this was a plot-flaw / bad setup to generate a narrow escape from the planet later.  This is not a comment, it is a genuine answer.  The answer is that the author just didn't come up with a better way of generating a narrow escape.

It was good that then Luke and Ben had to rush off the planet under fire to make for an exciting escape.  But it wasn't so good in that a critical viewer would realize that Ben Kenobi has various more subtle tactics to defend them.  He'd used more subtle tactics just prior and remained undetected.  Why wouldn't he use subtle tactics again and remain undetected right up until they left?  Why not just wave his fingers and say, "my friend is just a goofy teenager, not worth your time to bother with."

So, sorry, it was an imperfection in the plot.

Comment: While this is an interesting take, weren't the Storm Troopers after them because of the droids? Tatooine is a back-sands world. People get sliced/diced all the time. While the lightsaber was something out of the ordinary due to its rarity, the act itself was not uncommon. We can tell by how quickly the cantina got back to normal ... the patrons *just don't care*. Yes, the line was stated "interested in your handy work", but why were the Imperial troops at Mos Eisley in the first place ... *to find the droids*. This is the Hutt's world ... Imperial troops need not apply.

Comment: They'd snuck the droids past the stormtroopers undetected.  Yes, they were in a tough cantina where people looking for trouble wind up dead, but not by lightsabers unless there's a Jedi around.  Predictably Ben's use of the lightsaber alerted the storm troopers.

Comment: It might however be that the unlucky guy is not susceptible to Jedi hand waving (but that has not been stated explicitely in the movie). If he were resistant to Jedi mind tricks Obi-Wan would surely know that and therefore go for the quick draw.

Comment: He did in fact try more subtle tactics, unsuccessfully: ["This little one's not worth the effort. Come, let me get you something."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/quotes?item=qt0440634) Evazan was evidently not weak-minded enough for the Jedi mind trick to work.

Comment: @JoeC ... You've obviously missed my point. The Troopers were on Tatooine because of the droids. If not for the droids, the killing of dude would not have been an issue. They brought the droids past the Troopers with a wave of the hand and a "these are not the droids you're ***looking for***" ... which of course shows us why the troopers were in Mos Eisley in the first place, not to find some old man wielding a lightsaber.

Comment: Very good point! I said it before on these forums: asking this kind of questions that, in fact, reveal plot holes, only generate answers that the screenwriters probably never thought about. Just like the top answer here, we are not finding, but rather **building** a piece to fit the puzzle. Thus a lot of the time it is our answers that complete the story.

Comment: The reactions of the bar patrons says this is a fairly normal occurrence.  Still, Obi Wan would be a fool to think flashing around a light saber in a town full of Storm Troopers isn't going to attract attention, as is held true by the informant who tips them off.  That Obi Wan calmly puts his saber away and sits down to have a nice chat with Han and Chewie (and that Han is ok with this) always seemed odd to me, they should have gotten the hell out of there.  Even so, the movie does a good job of making *the audience* ok with this.

Comment: Paulster2.  The author can't have it both ways.  When the stormtroopers hear about the lightsaber they come guns blazing.  On the other hand the stormtroopers are looking for Droids only.  Evidence of a Jedi in their midst is of no interest to them.  That's why Kenobi pulls a lightsaber and doesn't even try to hide it.

Comment: Well someone answer this.  In the real original.  What we saw in the 1970s.  Did the guy knock Luke to the ground and point a blaster at him?  All I remember is Kenobi saying "let me get you something", the guy saying he and his friend don't like Luke and Luke saying "I'll be careful" and that guy shoving Luke and saying "you'll be dead" but not doing anything more alarming than that.

Comment: @JoeC They toss Luke and then draw blasters. The bartender yells blaster and dives. Then Obi-Wan cuts them both down in two strokes. The severed arm is shown on the ground holding a blaster (...and there are no cries of wounded survivors - he sliced them both to death.)

Answer (score 3):

In [*Star Wars: The Jedi Path*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) (Daniel Wallace, 2011) There is clear mention of how a lightsaber should be used to incapacitate an opponent. In brief removing an arm is considered a last resort when simply slicing the weapon is less damaging (and therefore more honourable/aligned with the Light path). Removing an opponent's arm is usually reserved for dueling when the opponent is still dangerous without a weapon (Dooku removing Anakin's arm, Vader removing Luke's.)

So as to "why" Kenobi removed his arm in the situation when he had every opportunity to just destroy the weapon probably requires another question to be asked. Three possibilities are:
a) Luke was in immediate danger, and possibly just destroying the blaster wouldn't get the point across (perhaps the attacker had other weapons);
b) perhaps it would have started a riot if he didn't show everyone else in the cantina he was serious;
c) as mentioned above, it was simply convenient for the scriptwriters.

Slightly off topic, but shortly after the scene we see Han shoot the bounty hunter. This sets up a contrast with Kenobi (who *could* have just as easily killed his opponent but did the more honourable thing of "only" removing his arm). This contrast is then continued during the trip to Alderaan, when Kenobi is schooling Luke in the ways of the force, while Han is deriding most of what he's being told as religious rhetoric.

So to answer the original question, in the brief seconds he had to appraise the situation, Kenobi realised that mind tricks wouldn't work, and serious (yet non-lethal) action was required. Even simply destroying the weapon would have been more in line with Jedi teachings (as would avoiding the confrontation and breaking his cover in the first place) but the situation had moved beyond a peaceful resolution.

Comment: Removing an arm would take almost everyone (save the [Black Knight][1]) out of an aggressive mood. 


  [1]: https://youtu.be/dhRUe-gz690 Even if the 2011 Jedi code calls for weapon destruction rather than amputation, the attackers were a pair of clearly irrational bloodthirsty maniacs. Cutting their guns (were that a reliable option in 1977 Star Wars) might have angered them but left them able to go get other blasters and come back, or to escalate or bring unwanted attention in other ways.

Comment: In a bar full of ruthless criminals, *not* acting ruthless and criminal (by sparing an opponent's life) attracts more attention than the alternative.

Comment: Oh, and I don't think Obi-Wan just removed one guy's arm in the scene. It looks to me like he kills two of them.