# Why did Obi-Wan lop off Ponda Baba's arm?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, obi-wan-kenobi

In the canonical novel *Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens:  The Weapon of a Jedi - A Luke Skywalker Adventure*, Luke recalls the incident in the Mos Eisley Cantina as follows [emphasis mine]:

> Luke’s mind flashed back to the Mos Eisley cantina, where two alien thugs had picked a fight with him. Ben had tried to play peacemaker, sensing Luke’s growing panic, but the aliens hadn’t been interested in peace. One had flung Luke into a table, then gone for his blaster, ready to gun Ben down.
>
> The old Jedi’s hand had dipped to the lightsaber on his belt, faster than anyone would have imagined a desert hermit could move. **His lightsaber sliced the blaster aimed at him in two, *then* carved through the thugs**.

This makes it clear that Obi-Wan delivered two strokes, and that the first had cut the alien's blaster in half;  only after this did Obi-Wan chop off his arm.

The question, then, is simple:

### Obi-Wan had already disarmed Ponda Baba (no pun intended) - so why did he continue the attack and remove the poor guy's arm when he no longer posed a threat?  Isn't this an unnecessary use of force (again, no pun intended)?

Comment: Obi-wan just loved chopping off arms.

Comment: He might have been a Jedi, but he was also an old man heavily outnumbered by the cantina's patrons (who are presumably the most wretched scum and villans Kenobi referred to in an earlier quote). It seems a decisive blow (with some degree of overkill included) would be the best way to end the conflict quickly and deter Ponda Baba's potential allies (seems to have worked, too).

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78704/whats-up-with-the-pun-not-intended-thing

Comment: He's a gun-toting thug who'd pose a threat to someone else as soon as he bought a new gun. Obi Wan was just making sure that didn't happen. Or at least delaying it a bit by making him get a robotic hand first.

Comment: He had the death sentence in twelve systems. He needed to be disarmed.

Comment: Your question makes an incorrect assertion; we see in the footage that Ponda Baby's blaster is still intact on the floor. See my answer.

Comment: @user45623 - That's a quote, not my assertion.

Comment: Ponda Baby is wearing the orange jacket. We don't even see him draw his blaster. The guy who's talking, the one with the bad nose, is Evazan. We see him point a blaster at Obi-Wan. Since your quote doesn't say who's blaster was cut, and we can see in the scene that Ponda Baby's blaster is intact, we know that Obi-Wan cut through _Evazan's_ blaster and cut off Ponda Baby's arm.

Comment: @user45623 - EXCELLENT POINT!  Upvoting your answer now.

Comment: Additionally, the passage you've quoted above incorrectly describes Evazan as an alien, so the claim that Obi-Wan cut anyone's blaster could be inaccurate - although he does appear to make a motion that would have cut through Evazan's blaster.

Comment: I appreciate the upvote, but is there any reason you haven't marked it as the answer?

Comment: @user45623 - I like to let questions sit a while to attract as many answers as possible so I can be sure I accept the best possible one.  I'd really prefer to accept an answer that includes canon references as well as observation.  So far, all we have is observation.

Comment: The film is a canon reference. You can see his blaster has not been cut in the film. Press pause at 6:46; the blaster being held by the severed arm on the ground clearly has not been cut in half.

Comment: @user45623 -  A canon reference explaining **why he chopped off Baba's arm**.  A quote from the novelization, or some other source.

Comment: Your original question is "so why did he continue the attack and remove the poor guy's arm when he no longer posed a threat?" He did still have a blaster and was still a threat. Anyway, this is silly, I'll leave you to decide what you want to do.

Comment: Good god, how many decades have I been writing "Baby" instead of "Baba"? I can't believe I just noticed it was "Baba" right now. -_-

Comment: @user45623 I fixed the "Baby"s in your answer.  And if the question didn't have answers already, I would edit it to just ask "Why did he cut off his arm" and not focus on the "when his blaster was already broken", but I can't do that now without invalidating the existing answers.

Answer (score 11):

Watch the scene closely. In the footage, we see Evazan draw his blaser; Ponda Baba is obscured behind Evazan in that shot so we can't see if he's drawn his blaster. Obi-Wan swirls his saber and then makes a single sweeping motion that knocks back both attackers at once. The camera then pans down to Ponda Baba's arm, still holding his intact blaster.

We don't see exactly what Obi-Wan is hitting with the lightsaber, but it looks like the initial swirl was intended to disable Evazan's blaster, while the second swing disabled both attackers. Again, Ponda Baba's blaster is still intact on the floor, **so the Aqualish was still holding an intact blaster when Obi-Wan cut off his arm.**

Comment: It actually looks to me like Obi-Wan makes two strokes, as the quote says.

Comment: I did a very bad job of describing what happens the first time. I've reworded most of it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DIzAaY2Jm-s?t=6m35s Two swings, one mostly off camera.

Comment: As I said in the edited answer, what I see is that he swirls the saber and then swings it. He draws it from his hip and swirls it in a circle in one continuous motion, then slashes it across both thugs at once. Regardless, the important part of the answer is that the question is wrong - he doesn't cut through Ponda Baby's blaster before he cuts his arm off.

Comment: I see him swing once at the blaster and once at the arm.  And the question is quoting a canon source.

Answer (score 10):

The way I see it, Obi-Wan had already decided to remove his arm when he drew the lightsaber. The initial strike to disarm Ponda (of his weapon) is just to be safe. It would only take a fraction of a second to pull the trigger, it could even happen unintentionally when being hit somewhere else. By destroying the weapon you minimize the risk of being hurt.

It has also been done before, **Mace Windu chops of Jango Fett's hand before removing his head** in *Attack of the Clones*.

The reasons for Obi-Wan's decision to cause serious damage is in my opinion explained by Eike. He was outnumbered and wanted to end the conflict quickly. Also, the "poor guy" is a wanted thug, Obi-Wan did the world a favor, if you ask me.

Comment: I'm not even sure that this sentence means there where two strikes, but just as well be that the light saber did not stop at the blaster (but then I'm not a native english speaker, so maybe I'm reading this wrong).

Comment: Oh, good point. I don't remember exactly how the attack is executed, so it may be just one swipe. My point is still the same though, I think he went for the gun first to minimize the risk of damage. Stopped by the gun on the way to the arm, if you will.

Comment: This answer doesn't take Evazan into account, and operates on the incorrect assertion made in the question that Ponda Baby's blaster was disabled at all.

Comment: @user45623 To be fair, the question isn't about him either. Answered Indirectly by saying Obi-Wan wanted to end the conflict quickly.

Comment: Also, in the Clone Wars movie, Anakin teaches Ashoka to destroy the weapon first, then attack.

Answer (score 5):

In a society with really good bionic limbs (such as AGFFY), cutting off a hand or arm was generally considered a humane way to win a fight.  Lopping off the head was considered (wait for it...) overkill in most cases and "not the Jedi way."

Comment: That's a great point, actually.

Comment: Also the Jedi had a really, really weird obsession with lopping off limbs ESPECIALLY hands. Don't believe me? See Hands of the Sith.

Comment: What does "AGFFY" mean?

Comment: @RedCaio - "A galaxy far, far away."

Comment: I might tend to agree with this…but why slash Evazan’s chest, then?

Answer (score 1):

The intention on Obi-Wan's part seems to be to end the fight **as quickly as possible**, in a way that results in the **minimum chance of a second attack** but **without necessarily killing the guy**. Merely chopping his gun in half would still leave him free to attack with his hands.

Disabling him was an immediate and highly effective way of ending the fight in just a few seconds. On top of that, it meant that he wasn't obliged to use the Force in the fight, something that would have immediately blown his cover:

> *Luke looked up from where he was sprawled on the floor and saw Ben’s
>   hand dart to his belt and draw a lightsaber. The blade flashed on and
>   swept past the blaster-wielding criminals. The disfigured man fell
>   back against the bar, a deep slash across his chest. The tusked alien
>   screamed and his right arm — severed at the elbow — fell to the floor,
>   still clutching the alien’s blaster.*
>
> *The entire fight had lasted only a matter of seconds. Luke hadn’t
>   noticed just when the band had stopped playing, but he was suddenly
>   aware that everyone had gone silent, and the only sound in the cantina
>   was the hum of Ben’s lightsaber. Ben maintained his position, holding
>   his lightsaber out from his body as he stared at his two defeated
>   opponents. He glanced out across the room. If anyone else had been
>   looking for a fight, the look in Ben’s eyes was enough to discourage
>   them.* - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: You don't think a lightsaber would kind of blow his cover, too?

Comment: @TylerH - You should ask that as a question "*Didn't Ben Kenobi using his lightsaber blow his cover?*". I actually have a nice canon answer for you.

Comment: @Richard - the "Didn't Ben Kenobi using his lightsaber blow his cover" question has been asked already, and you answered it.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85869/why-did-obi-wan-use-his-lightsaber-in-the-mos-eisley-cantina?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

1. If the blaster is removed from the situation, and you have a laser sword, and the other guy doesn't what further incentive do you need to prevent retaliation? You are armed, and they are not. Them attacking you in hand-to-hand; is basically suicide by jedi at that point. He could have simply put gotten their blasters, and the fight would have been over.
2. It's a lightsaber in a bar. His cover is blown, as only jedi use lightsabers.
3. We see that this is the kind of bar where people mind their own business. When Han shoots greedo later on; no-one intervenes, or tries to stop him when he leaves. Our conclusion should be that while two violent encounters in a day might be uncommon at the cantina, armed, violent conflict is common enough where everyone knows to stay out of everyone else's business. As such, there was no real reason for Obi-Wan to act as if he needed to intimidate everyone in the bar by brutalizing one of the perps. Neutralizing the perps, would have been enough. But no. He went back for seconds and took an arm, just because he felt like it.

Comment: Not only Jedi use lightsabers. It's an unusual weapon and one which Han thinks marks Ben out as being probably a Jedi-*enthusiast* rather than an actual Jedi.